# Why can I not down-vote?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

When I up-vote it goes well it even records itself in my profile. Though when I try to dow-nvote it says I need 125 reputation to vote. Why is that? Is that a bug?

Comment: This is most definitely by-design not a bug

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a bug. [You need to have 125 reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) to down-vote a question or answer.

Also, down-voting an answer will take one reputation from the down-voter.